# Problem upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: 19.10, 20.04

When trying to upgrade 19.10 to 20.04 with "update-manager -c -d" the software updater tells me the software is up to date and there is a new release available but when I select upgrade I get the message "Checking for a new Ubuntu release Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading." How do I overcome this?

The issue appears to be related to lldb. Both answers give the same result. Here is an example:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  lldb
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.

```
update-manager -c -d
```

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

Comment: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` *before* trying to release-upgrade. The message is saying that your 19.10 is not quite up-to-date.

Comment: DANGER DANGER... if you use the -d option, you'll get the development version. @user535733 has the correct answer to your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

and try to upgrade 19.10 to 20.04 with

```
update-manager -c -d
```

Comment: The issue here was that lldb was reported as being "kept back". once I forced an update with "sudo apt-get install lldb" all seemed to work